# kdb - resolving nested function when printing outer function body

Tags: kdb

I would like to print the function definition of any nested function when printing the definition of the outer function. Example:

```
g:{sin x}
f:{cos g x}
```

When I print `f` I get `{cos g x}` but I want to get `{cos {sin x} x}`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I am aware it is not possible to achieve that with in-build functions.

You can attempt to write your own function that does that but it will be a pain in the end. Something like this maybe:

```
q)m:string[v]!string value each v:value[f][3] except `
```

which creates a dictionary m :

```
q)m
,"g"| "{sin x}"
```

When given a function `value` returns a list containing `(bytecode;parameters;locals(context;globals);constants[0];...;constants[n];definition)`

However, if we pass a `symbol` to `value` it returns the value of that symbol (or function definition in this case).

You can then use `ssr` to replace the functions in `f` with the function definitions stored in your dictionary `m`.

```
q)ssr/[last value[f];key m;value m]
"{cos {sin x} x}"
```

but to ensure that your function is stable and adaptable to different functions would be very difficult.

For more details about how `value` have a look here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/metadata/#value

For `ssr` check this link: 
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/strings/#ssr

Comment: Note - your `value[f][9]` is version specific. Value only returns 5 items in v3.4 and prior. `last` might work for now but could be subject to change